# how to call Promise then function synchronously in react js

Tags: reactjs, promise, synchronous

I am working with React Js (frontend) and C# (Backend). I am facing a problem where I am calling a client api call from react screen (tsx file).
This api call is returning a promise object. But problem is in the api call we are using .then function for getting response of api call and this .then function is working asynchronously. It's not executing all the statements under .then function and immediately returning to the initial call function (.tsx file).

But I want some how my api call should execute completely (under .then function) and then it should return to the calling function.

Please see the code below-

```
    StudentDetails.tsx-
    ------------------
    StudentResults(id: number) {
        //api call
        this.StudentHandler.StudentDetail(id) //here id is the student id
        
        //other operations/statements (these statements should only be called after complete api execution)
        statement 1...
        statement 2...
        etc
    }

    StudentHandler.ts-
    ------------------

        StudentDetail(id: number){
         return  this.studentApi.getStudentDetail(id)
            .then(response => {
                
                statement 1... (this statement is calling after api execution)
                statement 2...  (and this statement is not calling after first statement. It's going to 'setStudentResults' function of tsx file and after executing                             remaining statemetns it's coming here again at 'statement 2')
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)                  
            })
}
```

Comment: Nice story! Would you mind posting some code?

Comment: It seems that you want your api call to pause the external execution till a response. Have you tried with async/await?

Comment: Share your source code where you are getting the issues exactly.

Comment: @OsmanysFuentes-Lombá, it seems await/async is also working same like promise.

Comment: `then` function is called _synchronously_; callback function(s) you pass to it as arguments are invoked _asynchronously_.

Comment: @Yousaf, how we can execute all the statements after completing api call synchronously, before going back to calling function ?

Comment: @sunil In your StudentDetail function you should directly return the promise. Then in StudentResults you can use await before calling StudentDetail. Remember that StudentResults must be an async function if you use await in it.

Answer (score 0):

I will rewrite your code to clarify the point of using async/await:

```js
async StudentResults(id: number) => {
        //api call
        // *************************
        // the await keyword pauses the execution of StudentResults till StudentDetail return something (successful or not)
        await this.StudentHandler.StudentDetail(id) //here id is the student id
        
        // ********************
        // this code is waiting for StudentDetail to complete
        //other operations/statements (these statements should only be called after complete api execution)
        statement 1...
        statement 2...
        etc
    }

    StudentHandler.ts-
    ------------------

        StudentDetail(id: number){
         return  this.studentApi.getStudentDetail(id)
            .then(response => {
                
                statement 1... (this statement is calling after api execution)
                statement 2...  (and this statement is not calling after first statement. It's going to 'setStudentResults' function of tsx file and after executing                             remaining statemetns it's coming here again at 'statement 2')
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)                  
            })
}
```